# Python 3.4.4 venv doesn't correctly set up activate/deactivate scripts on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm running into an odd issue.  I'm trying to use venv from Python 3.4.4.

When I issue the command

> python -m venv v_env

The v_env environment seems to get created.  However, I can't activate it because the files activate.bat, activate.ps1, and deactivate.bat are missing from the `Scripts` directory in the v_env directory.

I looked at the venv module in the Python 3.4.4 distribution.  I didn't see anything obvious, so I copied over the venv module to a local directory, renamed it lenv, and wrote the following throwaway script to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import lenv

lenv.main(['v_env'])
```

I still didn't see anything obvious, so I threw in print statements in the module.  My resulting file can be found at https://gist.github.com/pauluap/7e45b867eda4b0f94bfb59e38ddff9bf

When running everything, I got an output of:

```
v_env
1
2
3
4
5
6
11
['D:\\venvs\\s7dev\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']
```

Strangely enough, that seems to suggest that the script just kills itself after executing the subprocess call to "ensurepip"

I then suspected that there was an exception being caught silently or something, so I wrapped the subprocess call in a try/catch (Exception as e) construct, but I didn't see any exceptions printed, so I'm at a loss.

For whatever it is worth, if I request pip not be installed with the command

> python -m venv v_env --without-pip

then the scripts directory successfully get the activate/deactivate files.

If I then go ahead and issue the 'problematic' command:

> v_env\Scripts\python.exe -Im ensurepip --upgrade --default-pip

I get an output of:

```
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Collecting setuptools
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-7.1.2 setuptools-18.2
```

So things seem to be working there.  I'm at a loss.  I've tried doing this in PowerShell, PyCmd, and normal cmd.exe.

Hmm, well.  I'm having this problem on a Windows 7 machine.  I just tried creating a venv on another machine which is Windows 10.  Though, I think it has something more to do with the specific history of my Windows 7 machine rather than the 7/10 thing.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not limited to windows - I have come across exactly the same issue while working with a linux machine (linux mint 18 mate install). When I create a virtual environment using the --without-pip parameter the activation scripts are created; without the argument the scripts are absent.