# Problems setting up a python 3.7 virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, python-3.7, python-venv, virtual-environment

I am trying to create a new python 3.7 virtual environment on my local computer running Windows 8. I have python versions 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8 installed. Their exe's are named python36, python37, and python, respectively. All three are correctly added to PATH because I can enter each interpreter.

Within my new project's directory I tried to create a virtual environment with `python37 -m venv env`. It produced an error: `Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`, but it still created the directory. However the Scripts subfolder is empty except for `pythonw.exe`.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40352325/python-3-4-4-venv-doesnt-correctly-set-up-activate-deactivate-scripts-on-window) someone suggests doing `python37 -m venv env --without-pip`. When I tried this, the activation/deactivation scripts were created, but the virtual environment is using python 3.8.

It is my understanding that venv will create the virtual environment with what ever python exe you use to call it, so I don't understand how this can happen. I've verified that `python37` points to the correct place with `where python37`, and can even enter the 3.7 interactive interpreter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python venv env Fails - \[WinError 2\] The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669873/python-venv-env-fails-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I renamed the python exe's. I don't know exactly what goes wrong, but presumably at some point `venv` tries to find `python.exe` and is thrown off by the name.

Changing them back to `python.exe` and differentiating between the versions with their location fixed the problem.

Edit:
Check out Eryk's comments for more details.

Comment: The base "python.exe" must exist in order for the "python.exe" launcher to be copied over from "<installation>\Lib\venv\scripts\nt". Unfortunately it's hard coded. Even if you keep the original "python.exe" and use a hardlink or symlink (e.g. "python37.exe" -> "python.exe"), the base name of `sys.executable` will be "python37.exe", which causes the installation of pip to fail, since it tries to run "python37.exe" in the environment, which doesn't exist. In principle, it would work with a symlink if Python resolved `sys.executable` in Windows like it does in Unix. I consider this a bug.

Comment: As a workaround, you can create a "python37.lnk" file (shell shortcut) beside "python.exe" in the installation directory that runs it with the fully-qualified path. Clear the "start in" field to leave it empty in order to inherit the working directory of the caller that's running the shell link. Add ".LNK" to  `PATHEXT` in the system environment variables, and you'll be able to run `python37` from the command line in CMD or PowerShell. (Maybe use the name "python3.7.lnk", however, which is the normal name for this in Unix systems.)

Comment: Note that if you're using Explorer to create the shell link, by default it hides the .lnk extension, so make sure to just name it "python37" or "python3.7" without the extension. If Python is installed for all users in a system directory, create the shell link on your desktop, and then paste it into the installation directory. Explorer should prompt you to get administrator access.

Answer (score -1):

First create folder at any drive then go to that folder and install **virtualenv** package using pip.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then create your virtual environment.

```
mkvirtualenv myvirtualenv
```

Then use below command to activate virtualenv in windows.

```
myvirtualenv\Scripts\activate
```

After this you can install related package in current virtual environment.

[The Python Standard Library for Creating Virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)