# Python venv env Fails - [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

I installed the latest version of Python 3.8.2 on a Windows 10 machine. I previously had Python 3.7, which I uninstalled and confirmed in the System PATH it was no longer referenced.

After installing the latest version, I run through CMD as Admin:

```
py -m venv env
```

and I get this error:

Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\test_user\Documents\app_test\env'

I know the Python Path is in the System Path environmental settings, but not specifically for the user (don't know if that makes a difference?).

I have also tried to uninstall virtualenv using powershell and reinstaling, but have the same result.

Any ideas on where else to look to solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found out that Windows Defender now has a feature that blocks access/changes to system files. It added my documents folder by default, somehow preventing me from creating any folders in CMD despite having Admin Access. I hope this helps someone else!!

In short -- you may have to revise or disable your Windows 10 "Ranswomare Security Protection" setting to allow you to write files to your directories.

Comment: I second this, just run the commands with the command prompt in Administrator mode  instead of disabling Windows Defender

Answer (score 24):

I was facing the same problem. I found out that this is caused by renaming a copy python.exe executable to python3.exe. I did that because I have installed both Python 2.7 and Python 3.9 and configured *environmental variables* to use Python 2.7 with *python* command and Python 3.9 using *python3* command. So that my paths in environmental variables of Python 2 were above Python 3.

**To fix this edit your path variable so that Python 3 path will exist before Python 2 path.**

Also if you are using Python2 also, go to the installed location and create a copy of *python.exe* executable and rename it as *python2.exe*.

Then when you run *python* command it will direct to the *Python 3* and to use *Python 2* you can use *python2* command.

You can find more information on this by [following this issue](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5001).

Comment: I found the same problem exists even if I only created a symlink or copy of python.exe

Answer (score 17):

I work with 2 versions of Python 3.8 and 3.9. After changing my python.exe file to python38.exe I encountered this error. I searched and found [this answer](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5001#issuecomment-478027026):

> It looks like you might have renamed your python.exe executable to
> python3.exe? I got this same error after following install
> instructions that had me rename python.exe to be version-specific. **I
> renamed it back and python -m venv venv worked fine**.

I **changed back my 2 main python files to python.exe** and now I just run

```
py -3.8 -m venv env
```

or

```
py -3.9 -m venv env
```

Answer (score 9):

You probably encounter this error because you have two or more versions of Python on your machine.
When installing the second version, you:

- created the environment variable (ex `PYTHON37_HOME -> C:/Users/..Python/Python37`)
- specified this variable in `Path`.
- renamed the file `python.exe` to `python37.exe`

Now by opening the file `C:\Users\....\Python\Python37\Lib\venv\__init__.py` you can see that by executing the `setup_python()` function, `python.exe` cannot be found anymore in the `suffixes = ['python.exe', ...]` because we renamed it.

So you also have to rename `suffixes = ['python.exe', ...]` to `suffixes = ['python37.exe', ...]`.

Execute again `python37 -m venv venv` and it should work

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like the approach "disable your Windows 10 "Ranswomare Security Protection",

1. Then go to your python installation DIR on windows
2. right click and choose properties.
3. go security tab.
4. give all access to the current user by editing the permissions

[image]

Run the setup comment again, hope it'll work peacefully.

Answer (score 6):

I have realized whenever there is issue with multiple installation, especially the ones that occur rarely like setting up environment, I use full path to the python installation

```
[path to python installation folder]/python.exe -m venv env
```

Point to note here is that if you have a copy of python.exe named python2/3/27/37.exe be sure to call the original executable.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 10, you just need to run the script as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem:

```
python -m pip install -U pip --user //In Windows 
pip install -U pip --user //Linux, and MacOS
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I upgraded the pip inside of venv and that worked out .
my problem was that I could not install anything inside of venv like django but when I upgraded the pip everything went well.
the command you have to use is:

## Windows Command Prompt

```
> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

## Linux Terminal

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

## MacOS Terminal

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

To overcome this run `py -m venv env --user` or you can also manually run the script as administrator

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. And solve it using a simple trick.
Some packages need folder permission to get installed, todo so uses cmd with administrator access and then install whatever you want. Once the package or environment is installed it open the gates for normal user access to.

In a new windows system it is always a good idea to use cmd with administrator access to avoid these errors

Answer (score 0):

I got the WinError 2 because I have multiple python3 installed with different version and I was renamed the python.exe to other name. I have tried all solution offered in this post including turning down the firewall. Unluckily, I still got the winerror. So, I have to edit venv ****init**** in **[python path]/Lib/venv/**init**.py**. Find **python_exe** variable and change its value from **python.exe** to your new python executable name (in my case it's **python39.exe**). Also, find variable named **suffixes** and change the **python.exe** in suffix list to your python executable name. Finally, test it to make an env and activate it. The WinError Issues solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, simply using a shorter path fixed this error. Try creating your virual environment in the C: directory.Hope this helps.